# ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2006-1-1')) doesn't work for Python 3.11.1 but works for Python 3.10.*

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

A time series dataframe with index set as pandas timestamp. When plotting a vertical line on the ax for a specific time ex: '2006-1-1', the line doesn't show up for Python 3.11.1 but DOES show up for Python 3.10.2 and 3.10.6. Is there something going on the with new Python, or with the Pandas library? Thanks for the help.

Here is the code snippet:

```py
# Create the time index

df_sales['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['Date'])
df_sales = df_sales.set_index('Date')

# df_sales now has one column 'Sales' and Date as index

ax1 = df_sales.plot.line()
ax1.axvline(x=pd.Timestamp('2006-1-1'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: there is no Python 10.x or 11.x - do you mean 3.10 etc. ? Also, plotting is not built-in, you'll have to use packages such as matplotlib (or pandas). Which versions of those are you using?

Comment: Yes, 3.11 and 3.10 for Python. And yes, matplotlib is imported, version 3.7.0